# wp-admin throws 404 when accessed from some IPs

Tags: 404-error

When I am trying to access wp-admin I am getting a 404 page for some specific internet connections on some days.

I have tried deactivating Jetpack, that did not solve the issue. Except for Jetpack I don't have any plugin activated which has anything to do with site security.

Answer (score 0):

May be your hosting provider have some restrictions. You can contact to your hosting providers to fix the issue. Or you can take help by this documentation to fix the issue =>https://www.fixrunner.com/404-error/